lightway-laser client can't normal start
I'm using lightway-laser, according to https://github.com/expressvpn/lightway-laser?tab=readme-ov-file#build-and-run-clientserver describe, I can start server, but when I use command scripts/run_iperf_client.sh, I get below error:
Resolved to target  server 
Check that we have connectivity to the lightway server
ping: : Name or service not known 

I try to modify run_iperf_client.sh at scripts directory and run command scripts/run_iperf_client.sh with sudo/root permission. But I always get error that I can't normal start client, more details please see https://github.com/expressvpn/lightway-core/issues/170
How can I solve this problem? Anyone can help me? Thank you.
